# Import .cmp list into a folder in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, import

I have backup of a list(.cmp) file. I want to import it to some folder under PublishingImages in Sharepoint 2016. 

How should I do it. Some code snippets will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the command below:

Import-SPWeb  [-Identity]  -Path

For more information about Import-SPWeb, you can refer to the article below:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/import-spweb?view=sharepoint-ps